# Obtaining a smooth transition in an image slider animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations, keyframe

**THE AIM**

Obtain a smoother transition between images. At the moment I have a white background between images for a few milliseconds.

**THE PROBLEM**

Apparently I cannot properly replicate this part of my code as I don't think you can use links in *background-image: url(...)*. In my actual code, I'm using relative paths.

The problem is the white background between picture transition when they first load and are not save in the cache. When starting again the slider, the transition is smoother, i.e. the white background is not shown.

**SUMMARY**

I would like to obtain a smoother transition between pictures when they first load and are not save in the cache. How could this be done? *(jQuery is also welcomed)*

```css
    h1 {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      margin: 20vh 0;
      background-color: lightblue;
      padding: 50px;
    }


    @keyframes slide {
      0% {
        background-image: url("https://s.ftcdn.net/v2013/pics/all/curated/RKyaEDwp8J7JKeZWQPuOVWvkUjGQfpCx_cover_580.jpg?r=1a0fc22192d0c808b8bb2b9bcfbf4a45b1793687");
      }

      25% {
        background-image: url("https://s.ftcdn.net/v2013/pics/all/curated/RKyaEDwp8J7JKeZWQPuOVWvkUjGQfpCx_cover_580.jpg?r=1a0fc22192d0c808b8bb2b9bcfbf4a45b1793687");
      }

      25.01% {
        background-image: url("https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/micro-peacock-feather-hd-imagebest-260nw-1127238584.jpg");
      }

      50% {
        background-image: url("https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/micro-peacock-feather-hd-imagebest-260nw-1127238584.jpg");
      }

      50.1% {
        background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/326055/pexels-photo-326055.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500");
      }

      75% {
        background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/326055/pexels-photo-326055.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500");
      }

      75.1% {
        background-image: url("https://media3.s-nbcnews.com/j/newscms/2019_41/3047866/191010-japan-stalker-mc-1121_06b4c20bbf96a51dc8663f334404a899.fit-760w.JPG");
      }

      100% {
        background-image: url("https://media3.s-nbcnews.com/j/newscms/2019_41/3047866/191010-japan-stalker-mc-1121_06b4c20bbf96a51dc8663f334404a899.fit-760w.JPG");
      }
    }

    .slider {
      background-image: url("https://s.ftcdn.net/v2013/pics/all/curated/RKyaEDwp8J7JKeZWQPuOVWvkUjGQfpCx_cover_580.jpg?r=1a0fc22192d0c808b8bb2b9bcfbf4a45b1793687");
      background-size: cover;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center;
      animation: slide 30s infinite;
    }

    .load {
      animation: slide 2s;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="slider"></div>
  <div class="load"></div>
  <h1>SOME CONTENT</h1>
```

**UPDATE**

The images are now shown as `<div class="slider"></div>` was missing before. This was pointed out in the first answer below. However, the white background between images is still there.

Comment: Ideally, your images should have the same width, background-image set to contain, and may I ask why are those keyframes with decimal values like 25.01 and then 50.1%?

Comment: Why you have defined every image two times (I mean those  0.1%)?

Comment: without it the images show a sort of bouncing effect. By having the pictures twice this effect was avoided and they simply transition from one to another...

Comment: CSS3 linear transitions

Answer (score 1):

Your slider and load  divs didn't show because there was nothing in them to begin with and no default height specified in the css. I have given the slider a height of 30vh and a width of 100% (I went with that one for demo purposes). I reduced the margin/padding around the h1 (there's a lot!) just so you could see the images better in the snippet. Still might be viewed better full screen.

I added an animation timing (ease-in-out) to the css to make the start and end of the animation slower to make the transition seem a little easier on the eye.  The default is ease which makes it fast in the middle; by changing the transition speed, your animation may  appear a little smoother.

Hope this helps

```css
    h1 {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      margin: 2vh 0;
      background-color: lightblue;
      padding: 15px;
    }


    @keyframes slide {
      0% {
        background-image: url("https://s.ftcdn.net/v2013/pics/all/curated/RKyaEDwp8J7JKeZWQPuOVWvkUjGQfpCx_cover_580.jpg?r=1a0fc22192d0c808b8bb2b9bcfbf4a45b1793687");
      }

      25% {
        background-image: url("https://s.ftcdn.net/v2013/pics/all/curated/RKyaEDwp8J7JKeZWQPuOVWvkUjGQfpCx_cover_580.jpg?r=1a0fc22192d0c808b8bb2b9bcfbf4a45b1793687");
      }

     25.01% {
        background-image: url("https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/micro-peacock-feather-hd-imagebest-260nw-1127238584.jpg");
      }

      50% {
        background-image: url("https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/micro-peacock-feather-hd-imagebest-260nw-1127238584.jpg");
      }

     50.1% {
        background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/326055/pexels-photo-326055.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500");
      }

      75% {
        background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/326055/pexels-photo-326055.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500");
      }

      75.1% {
        background-image: url("https://media3.s-nbcnews.com/j/newscms/2019_41/3047866/191010-japan-stalker-mc-1121_06b4c20bbf96a51dc8663f334404a899.fit-760w.JPG");
      }

      100% {
        background-image: url("https://media3.s-nbcnews.com/j/newscms/2019_41/3047866/191010-japan-stalker-mc-1121_06b4c20bbf96a51dc8663f334404a899.fit-760w.JPG");
      }
    }

    .slider {
      display:inline-block;
      background-image: url("https://s.ftcdn.net/v2013/pics/all/curated/RKyaEDwp8J7JKeZWQPuOVWvkUjGQfpCx_cover_580.jpg?r=1a0fc22192d0c808b8bb2b9bcfbf4a45b1793687");
      background-size: cover;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center;
      animation: slide 5s ease-in-out infinite;
       height:30vh;
       width:100%;
    }

    .load {
      animation: slide 5s infinite;
    }
```

```html
 
  <h1>SOME CONTENT</h1>
  <div class="slider"></div>
```

Comment: Oh what a mistake. Thanks for pointing that out! If you have a look at your snippet, you'd notice that in the first run of the images (before they start repeating themselves) there are a few milliseconds of a white background between images, i.e. during the transition. After that, the white background is gone.... Is there a way of making that white background gone between images?

Comment: @Joehat I actually don't notice that in my browser (I'm using the latest chrome) but I presume if you're noticing some white in your browser, that it doesn't show the second time because the images are cached. I'm not going to look at this anymore today, it's christmas eve, i'm going to celebrate. Hope you work it out and that  the answer shed some light. If it did, a christmas vote would be nice ;. Happy christmas and new year..!